How to Load Multiple Files Individually from an RDATA File
My office primarily uses R for data analysis, although I use python. A handful of people use excel. Our office uses a single data pull each day to do all of our analyses so if we get different answers, we know it's not because of use hitting the databases at different times. The major problem with this is we save that data pull as an .RData file, that can only be opened in R.
I'm working on converting that data file into something more universal such as a json file. That way python can open it easily, and I believe excel can open it if you use powerquery or something (I don't use excel much for analysis). This would make it easily accessible to everyone in our office without using multiple programs each time we do something.
The problem I'm running into is that I can't find a good way to access each individual item saved in the .rdata file and save it off as a json file. It looks like there are 56 dataframes and variables saved in the .rdata file, and I want to convert each of the dataframes to a json file.
I'm open to other formats if someone has a good suggestion, but for context, our IT department is completely incompetent so we can't get software upgrades, and we can't load python and R packages ourselves. Our installed R libraries can't handle hdf5 or parquet, and our installed python packages can't handle parquet. I also don't want to completely screw the excel people, although they've by necessity learned some R, so it doesn't need to be usable in excel.
I've tried
test_import = load(my_data)
print(test_import)
But so far I've just been able to get lists of the items that are in the file.

Conceivably if you are just loading in an RDATA file and write each of the dataframes inside the list to a json, or any other format, you can do something like this
library(tidyverse)

sim_data_frames = \(n = 100){
  tibble(
    x = rnorm(n),
    y = 0.5 * x + rnorm(n)
  )
}

data_list = replicate(56, sim_data_frames(), simplify = FALSE)


save(data_list, file = "data_list.RDATA")


load("data_list.RDATA")

names(data_list) = paste0("data_", 1:56)

names_vec = names(data_list)
dir.create("individual_data_files")

invisible(map2(data_list, names_vec, \(x,y) jsonlite::write_json(x, here::here("individual_data_files",
                                                               paste0(y, ".json")))))

invisible(map2(data_list, names_vec, \(x,y) xlsx::write.xlsx(x, here::here("individual_data_files",
                                                                   paste0(y, ".xlsx")))))

Where map2 will iterate over each element of the list and the names vector to save a json file. If there is a mix of information like this
char_vec = "this is not a data frame" 

data_list2 = append(data_list, char_vec)


You can use keep to get rid of the non-data frame elements like this

data_list_saving = data_list2 |> 
  keep(\(x) is.data.frame(x))

length(data_list_saving) ; length(data_list)
#> [1] 56
#> [1] 56

Created on 2024-05-15 with reprex v2.1.0

I was trying to convert this to be usable with my data, and ran into a few errors, so I tried  running this exactly as it's written and still am getting several errors. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with R to really see what's causing the errors.
In the code as written, I'm getting an error in line 3:
Error: unexpected input in "sim_data_frames = "

tibble(



x = rnorm(n),



y = 0.5 * x + rnorm(n)


)
I've also been getting errors in line 23 both as written and when I modify it:
Error: unexpected ')' in " paste0(y, ".json"))"


For line 3 do you still get an error when you swap out the “\” for “function”?  My guess for line 23 is just a case of unmatched parenthesis.

Trying sim_data_frames = funtion(n = 100){
tibble(
x = rnorm(n),
y = 0.5 * x + rnorm(n)
)
}
Does still produce the an error
Error: unexpected '{' in "sim_data_frames = funtion(n = 100){"
For the second one, that was my guess, but I looked thru it several times, and all the parenthesis matched. I even tried deleting one and it still threw the error, so that one's really confusing me.

Ahh it looks like the error related to the sim_data_frames function is that you have funtion versus function this function was mostly to try to imitate the RData file you were working with. Does the error persist if you change the the map code to map2(data_list, names_vec, \(x,y) jsonlite::write_json(x,  paste0("individual_data_files/",y, ".json")))?
